# Dynamic variable creation using eval JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need something like an associative array that contains pairings of variable name / element ID.

Looping through this array/object, assign the element ID to the variable name that is its counterpart. Something like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqL4pyg/1/)

HTML:

```
<input id="fld_1" class="input" type="text" value="bob" /><br>
<input id="fld_2" class="input" type="text" value="fred" /><br>
<input id="fld_3" class="input" type="text" value="pat" /><br>
<input id="mybutt" class="btn" type="button" value="Test" />
```

JS:

```
objFields = {'f1':'fld_1', 'f2':'fld_2', 'f3':'fld_3'};
arrErrors = [];

$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    alert('iii');
    for (var key in objFields){
     //   eval(key = objFields[key]);
        eval(key) = objFields[key];
        alert('f1: ' +f1);
    }
});
```

There is no requirement to using `eval`, I just need to turn the key into the variable name.

Where have I gone wrong?

### Solution

JCOC611 got it right, but I wasn't clear in how I asked the question. As demo'd in [this revised fiddle which implements JCOC611's solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqL4pyg/2/), the variable/field names *had to be used to get the value of the field contents,* like this:

```
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    for (var key in objFields){
        var tmp = objFields[key];
        eval('var ' + key+ ' = $("#' +tmp+ '").val()');
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you must set a variable and not use `objFields["f1"]`?

Comment: `window[key]` which would make a global variables, but would advise against putting arbitrary variables into global scope.

Comment: I think you are probably dealing with the problem of not knowing how to access items from an asynchronous call outside the function call if you think you need to write data into the global scope. The proper approach here is callbacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* you know what you are doing and are *absolutely* sure about it, then use this:

```
eval(key + " = " + JSON.stringify(objFields[key]));
```

Or, if you want local variables:

```
eval("var " + key + " = " + JSON.stringify(objFields[key]));
```

Otherwise, I advice you implement one of the other answers.

Comment: Weird, when you do `eval('var testing = 5')` in the browser's console, it's still created as a property of the `window` object, but when you [do it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6aq97cs/), it isn't. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Stryner: using `var` in the browser's console pretty much does nothing because it is not inside any code block (it is in the global scope).

Comment: @Stryner, look at the left side options, your JS code is run inside a onLoad function call, you can change it to _no wrap in head_ and then you will see it set as a global variable

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `eval()` at all, and you want to avoid it. All you really need to do is:

```
for (var key in objFields){
    alert(key+': '+objFields[key]);
    window[key] = objFields[key];
}
```

Will give you:

```
'f1':'fld_1'
'f2':'fld_2'
'f3':'fld_3'
```

Where:

```
f1 = 'fld_1';
f2 = 'fld_2';
f3 = 'fld_3';
```

Comment: You are also right, Spencer, but I wasn't clear in how I asked the question. Here is [the revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqL4pyg/3/) using your solution.  It works great, but eval is still required for the actual purpose.

Comment: @crashwap Sure, I mean it's a good idea to avoid `eval()` in general if this is user input in any way, as it's possible to be abused.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a global variable, it is as simple as:

```
window[key] = objFields[key];
```

or

```
 window.key = objFields[key];
```

The second one is a bit less `weird name` immune.

Comment: the second one wouldnt work as op wants, as you would just be creating a variable/property named `key`

Answer (score 0):

The eval function runs a string add code and returns the result.

What your code did was evaluate the vague of key which is undefined and then tried to set it to a new value.
Is like writing 5=4;

Correct syntax:

```
eval('var ' + key + ' = ' + objFields[key]);
```

Comment: I want your answer to be correct because your name is so close to `eval`

Comment: JCOC611 is correct -- JSON.stringify is required, unless the var moved outside the eval expression.  See [the revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxqL4pyg/2/)